# Creating Sharepoint App -> central admin error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, central-administration, app

I am creating a SharePoint app , everything went fine . But when I configure Application url, I get below error:

Sorry, something went wrong Settings or services required to complete this request are not currently available. Try this operation again later. If the problem persists, contact your administrator.

Comment: have you tried to increase the timeout time in the central administration application pool?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22733.sharepoint-2013-sorry-apps-are-turned-off.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The logs say :
Memory gates checking failed because the free memory (144322560 bytes) is less than 5% of total memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming requests.  To resolve this, either reduce the load on the machine or adjust the value of minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService on the serviceHostingEnvironment config element. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

1. Opened Task Manager and found the server was consuming complete memory on the box. 
   We can follow below steps to resolve the issue: 
   a. Perform IISRESET so that it will release the memory. This is only a short-term solution
   b. Increase memory on the SharePoint servers as a long-term solution

Thanks to below link:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22733.sharepoint-2013-sorry-apps-are-turned-off.aspx